# How to stop Ubuntu in Windows 10 from outputting files with #000D added to the extension?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How do you stop Ubuntu in Windows 10 outputting a `.txt#000D` file instead of  a `.txt` file I need to be outputted?

Im using this shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
sudo chmod a+rwx /home/User/FYP_Pastec/TextFiles/*
sudo rm -f /home/User/FYP_Pastec/TextFiles/*
sudo curl -X POST --data-binary '@/home/User/FYP_Pastec/Currency_Test/Test_FiveEuro01.jpg' 'http://localhost:4212/index/searcher' > /home/User/FYP_Pastec/TextFiles/Results_From_cURLCommand.txt
sudo cp /home/User/FYP_Pastec/TextFiles/Results_From_cURLCommand.txt /mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/Pastec_Test_Connection/Text/
```

and because its being outputted like so:

[image: Screenshot of the outputted file]

The last line to copy the file thinks it doesn't exist.

Also the Ubuntu version I am running is 16.04 as a subsystem to Windows 10.

Comment: When `ls` is done it shows them with `.txt?` ... Why is the question mark there

Comment: It worked fine at first but I changed the name of the output file and this started. Then when i changed it back  it continued to do it.

Comment: @Jay1995, which text editor did you use to create your script? Maybe the issue is connected with the cartrage return characters, if you are using some Windows editor. What is the output of `cat -v <script-file>`? Please review this article: [Remove Carriage Return on Linux or Unix](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/sed-remove-m-and-line-feeds-under-unix-linux-bsd-appleosx/)

Comment: I used notepad++